# AAD B2C custom policy inheritance: can <BasePolicy> chain forever?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a situation where each of our customers has a separate identity provider, and we need to create an <IdentityProvider> for each customer. There could be over 100 customers. If we define every customer's <IdentityProvider> in a single <TrustFrameworkPolicy> file, then every time we add, remove, or change a customer, we'll need to replace the entire file and overwrite the settings of every other customer. Instead, we'd like to define each customer's <IdentityProvider> in a separate <TrustFrameworkPolicy> file and chain them together using the <BasePolicy> element.

Is there a limit on how many <TrustFrameworkPolicy> files can be chained together using <BasePolicy>?  For instance, could we chain together 100 custom policy files, each inheriting from a preceding one in its <BasePolicy>? If this is allowed, will it kill performance?

Comment: Documentation says inheritance level is 10 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits#azure-ad-b2c-configuration-limits

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comment. Thanks wojtekdo!